# Xamarin Forms Play a sound Asynchronously

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, task

I can successfully play sounds using Xamarin forms (Android and iOS) however I also need to achieve the following:

- I need to await so that if multiple sounds are 'played', one will complete before the next.
- I need to return a boolean to indicate whether operation was a success.

Here is my current simplified code (for the iOS platform):

```
    public Task<bool> PlayAudioTask(string fileName)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        string filePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), Path.GetExtension(fileName));

        var url = NSUrl.FromString(filePath);

        var _player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);

        _player.FinishedPlaying += (object sender, AVStatusEventArgs e) =>
            {
                _player = null;
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            };

        _player.Play();

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

To test the method, I have tried calling it like so:

```
    var res1 = await _audioService.PlayAudioTask("file1");
    var res2 = await _audioService.PlayAudioTask("file2");
    var res3 = await _audioService.PlayAudioTask("file3");
```

I had hoped to hear the audio for file1, then file2, then file3.  However I only hear file 1 and the code doesn't seem to reach the second await.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue here is that the `AVAudioPlayer _player` was being cleared out before it was finished.  If you were to add debugging to your `FinsihedPlaying`, you'll notice that you never hit that point.

Try these changes out, I made a private `AVAudioPlayer` to sit outside of the `Task`

*(I used the following guide as a reference https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/avaudioplayer/)*

```
    public async void play()
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Play 1");
        await PlayAudioTask("wave2.wav");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Play 2");
        await PlayAudioTask("wave2.wav");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Play 3");
        await PlayAudioTask("wave2.wav");

    }


    private AVAudioPlayer player;  // Leave the player outside the Task

    public Task<bool> PlayAudioTask(string fileName)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        // Any existing sound playing?
        if (player != null)
        {
            //Stop and dispose of any sound
            player.Stop();
            player.Dispose();
        }

        string filePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), Path.GetExtension(fileName));

        var url = NSUrl.FromString(filePath);

        player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);

        player.FinishedPlaying += (object sender, AVStatusEventArgs e) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DONE PLAYING");
            player = null;
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        };


        player.NumberOfLoops = 0;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Start Playing");
        player.Play();

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

[image: application output]

Comment: **Apple's AVAudioPlayer Reference** - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/

Comment: **Xamarin - Playing Sound with AVAudioPlayer** - https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/avaudioplayer/